# Sockets - Difference between C and Java sending

Tags: java, c, sockets, nio

I am converting a Java application (using NIO) to C sockets and am encountering a problem. At the same time, I am using grinder, as a TCPProxy, to see what's been transferred.

I have 4 lines for which i need to send to the client as part of the handshake.

```
Hello~Server\r\n
Hello1~Server1\r\n
Hello2~Server2\r\n
Hello3~Server3\r\n
```

For the Java application (using NIO), each string was sent out after every Java NIO flip(). That is to say the above 4 lines are sent out one at a time.

I have the following pseudo- code for Java.

1. Clear Buffer,
2. Put string into Buffer,
3. Put size of string,
4. Flip.

For C sockets, all 4 char arrays were sent out together even though I have 4 separate send()s.

Stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have nagle and all coalescing turned off?

Comment: Hey Peter. I was reading about nagle but I have not turned it off yet.I'll try that. Thanks matey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is a stream oriented protocol. That is to say, it should not matter how the stream is split up. So a design which requires splitting up the stream at specific boundaries is probably using TCP wrongly.

Having said that, you can attempt to turn of "lumping" via `setsockopt` with the `TCP_NODELAY` option.

Answer (score 1):

The messages sent by your C code are probably getting coalesced into a single packet by [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).  You can disable this by [setting the TCP_NODELAY option](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.16.shtml) on the socket
to disable Nagle's algorithm.  However, you should bear in mind that TCP is not required to respect your message boundaries, so your protocol should have its own way of determining when a complete message has been received, rather than depending on a 1-1 correspondence between send() and recv() calls at the endpoints.

Comment: Jim, thanks for the heads up. I'll bear your words in mind. Thanks again for the speedy response! Speaking of which, would any one know whether Java nio disables Nagle's algo?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to give suggestions to me (the slow one). I've tried enabling TCP_NODELAY but it didn't fix the 'problem'. Why i said 'problem' - answer below.

I looked into my send() and noticed that I used a sizeof(message) instead of a strlen(message). sizeof() - gets the size of bytes to be sent. strlen() - gets the number of chars to be sent, excluding the \0.

I was quite naive to follow what the man page on ubuntu had said.

yakult121$man send

> ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buffer, size_t len, int flags);

I thought the argument, size_t len was meant to use sizeof() as I had used it for memset().

yakult121$man memset

> void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);

I also finally understood that socklen_t and size_t are different datatypes.

Thanks all once again. I could not have found the problem and would continue to point the finger at Nagle's algo.

Comment: actually `sizeof` is a compile-time thing: it evaluates to the number of chars taken up by the expression or type. do _not_ automatically use `sizeof` when you need to produce something of type `size_t` - you need to think of what you want to do.